# java 8 getter with default value on null object or attribute

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, option-type

I'm not quite proficient in Java, so I would like to know if I'm doing right here.

As the title states, the code below is for getting some default reply when fetching an attribute on a null object, or an object with a null attribute value.

this seems to work, but I'd be thankful if someone could tell me if I'm looking at the problem the right way.

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class ReplyOnNullPointer {

    static class C{
        private String a;
        public C(String a){this.a=a;}
        public String getAtt(){return a;}
    }


    private static<I,R> R getterWithDefault(I o,Function<? super I,R> mapper, R orDefault){
        return Optional.ofNullable(o).flatMap(x->Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(x))).orElse(orDefault);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C o1 = null;
        C o2 = new C(null);
        C o3 = new C("attribut");

        System.out.println("o3 : "+o3);
        System.out.println("o3.att : "+o3.getAtt());
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("o2 : "+o2);
        System.out.println("o2.att : "+o2.getAtt());
        System.out.println("o2.att : "+Optional.of(o2).flatMap(x->Optional.ofNullable(x.getAtt())).orElse("<nope>"));
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("o1 : "+o1);
        System.out.println("o1.att : "+Optional.ofNullable(o1).flatMap(x->Optional.ofNullable(x.getAtt())).orElse("<nope>"));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("o1.att : "+getterWithDefault(o1,C::getAtt,"<nope>"));
        System.out.println("o2.att : "+getterWithDefault(o2,C::getAtt,"<nope>"));
        System.out.println("o3.att : "+getterWithDefault(o3,C::getAtt,"<nope>"));

    }
}
```

the ouput looks like this :

```
o3 : ReplyOnNullPointer$C@15db9742
o3.att : attribut

o2 : ReplyOnNullPointer$C@6d06d69c
o2.att : null
o2.att : <nope>

o1 : null
o1.att : <nope>

o1.att : <nope>
o2.att : <nope>
o3.att : attribut
```

thanks for your corrections/opinions/advices

Comment: SO is probably not the best place to ask this. You should go here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Alfabravo Close a question if it's off-topic here. Whether or not it's on-topic somewhere else, Code Review or another SE site, is quite irrelevant.

Comment: @Mast hi! this comment was generated by SO when I voted to close. Also, it IS relevant as the question might be moved to said site in SE so OP can get useful help (and that's the purpose of this all, right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just:

```
Optional.ofNullable(o).map(mapper).orElse(orDefault);
```

You don't need `flatMap(x->Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(x)))`, this is exactly what chaining `map` on `Optional` is doing.

Comment: well, mapper is not of Optional type (it is Function<? super I,R> mapper, and not of Function<? super I,Optional<R>> mapper as requiered in javadoc). this is because mapper can be a getter from a random class that does not use Optionals. So I thought I should add the Optional enclosing by hand.. but if you say it's already done..

Comment: @user3617487 `Optional.map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper)` returns `Optional<U>`, not `U`. So you don't need a getter which returns optional etc.